# How to correctly get the number of columns from a JDBC query

Tags: java, jdbc

I have this code that converts a JDBC result set into a list of hash tables:

```
private static ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> convertResultSet(ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException {
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> map = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
    ResultSetMetaData rsmd = resultSet.getMetaData();
    int nColumns = rsmd.getColumnCount();
    while(resultSet.next()) {
        HashMap<String, Object> hash = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        for (int i = 0; i < nColumns; i++)
        {
            hash.put(rsmd.getColumnName(i), resultSet.getObject(i));
        }
        map.add(hash);
    }
    return map;
}
```

but when run, it throws a "Column index out of range." exception.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please post the exact error with complete stack trace.

Comment: Also, maybe you want to use `Map<String, Object> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>>();` instead of `ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> map = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();`

Answer (score 4):

As stated in the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html#getColumnName%28int%29), the index for the getColumnName(i) starts from 1, not from 0.

Comment: @Dabloons I think this is caused by historical reasons, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/616135/in-jdbc-why-do-parameter-indexes-for-prepared-statements-begin-at-1-instead-of

Comment: All indexes in the SQL Standard and in JDBC are 1-based. The fact that indexes in most languages these days are 0-based is largely due to languages like C and pointer manipulation.