# SOLID Table Error 13037: Illegal DOUBLE PREC constant

Tags: java, jdbc, ibm-soliddb

I am getting the following error while trying to add a record using my Java JDBC code into SolidDB.

Following the the method that throws the exception:

```
    public void addData(User data) {
    Connection conn = null;
    try {
        conn = dataSource.getConnection();
        if (conn == null || conn.isClosed()) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not open connection");
        }
        String query="INSERT INTO USER "
                + "(ID, NAME, PASSWORD, ENABLED, REQUIRE_RESET)"
                + "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?);";

        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        // "ID" column is INTEGER, and partition field in UserData is int.
        ps.setString(1, data.getId());
        ps.setString(2, data.getName());
        ps.setString(3, data.getPassword());
        // "ENABLED" column is INTEGER, and enabled field in UserData is boolean.
        ps.setInt(4, data.isEnabled()? 1:0); 
        ps.setString(5, data.isRequireReset()?"Y":"N");
        if (ps.executeUpdate() < 1) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not save User, executeUpdate() returned a value < 1");
        }

    } Catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new DataLayerException("Could not save the User Data.", e);
    } finally {
        if (conn != null) {
            try {
                conn.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried by directly hard-cording the values still it fails.
And the insert will be successful if I remove the "ID" & "ENABLED" columns from the insert statement.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the exception/stacktrace you get when you run this code?

Comment: @Alfabravo I have only this info: Nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: [Solid JDBC 7.0.0.2 Build 2012-04-20] SOLID Table Error 13037: Illegal DOUBLE PREC constant. I don't have access to the log.

Comment: According to some user manual out there, that error means you're introducing soble double precision data as a constant and it's not a valid double. Are you sure about the data type of the fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got the solution and it is because of a stupid syntax error.
When I get rid of the semicolon at the end, it worked!

Comment: Thanks! it worked when remove semicolon at the end of the query.

Answer (score 1):

`PreparedStatement` indexes are [1-based](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/616135/in-jdbc-why-do-parameter-indexes-for-prepared-statements-begin-at-1-instead-of) (see also [setXX javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setArray-int-java.sql.Array-)). Because you use 0, and the driver doesn't warn you, everything is "shifted" causing the issue.

Fix:

```
ps.setString(1, data.getId());
ps.setString(2, data.getName());
ps.setString(3, data.getPassword());
ps.setInt(4, data.isEnabled()? 1:0); 
ps.setString(5, data.isRequireReset()?"Y":"N");
```

Comment: Good catch +1 for it, I have corrected my code and re-run it, still getting the same error!.

Comment: So I am going to update my question with your correction, thanks.